# Using Cron to check and reboot a PHP script

Tags: php, cron

I have a script that will be running a while() loop continuously, execute.php. It will be triggered initially via Cron to start at a certain time and will run the while loop (sleeping periodically) until we reach a predetermined end time which will be controlled by a MySQL table detailing start and end times.

On each loop of the script I will be putting the current timestamp into a DB table. I want a Cron task to then run every 5 minutes or so and make sure the script hasn't crashed and if it has, then to revisit execute.php and start it up again. Obviously I can set a Cron task to run something like check.php that simply checks the timestamp table and makes sure it's not more than 2 minutes old or so, but how do I then make that script reboot execute.php?

The only solution I can think of is to have check.php schedule a new Cron task for a few seconds ahead to run execute.php but this seems clunky. The crux of the question is: is there a way to get one PHP script to run another in this context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move this whole locking logic into you php script. Since you already have everything you need (database credentials, config files with the table names...), just structure it like this:

1. Connect database, load setup, etc...
2. Check the last update time's difference with the current time
3. In case it's fresh enough, `exit`
   In case it isn't fresh enough kick of the `while()`

There are various daemon management software if you can install things on the server like [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), [god](http://godrb.com/), or you could simply use [init](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_inittab.htm) with a respawn line.

Comment: I don't see how, if execute.php crashes for whatever reason, how it can look after itself? Surely some external process, completely unrelated to it, needs to check it's still working OK?

Comment: It doesn't have to, the cron will start it periodicly and if it did crashed it will just restart, otherwise just the new one will exit and the old one will run as before. If you have cron start it every 5 minute that means you will have 5 minutes of "offline" time at most.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, instead of having Cron start the task just once, we get it to run every 5 minutes between the start and end time. The only issue here is what if it reruns the script mid execution? Each loop could last 10 seconds as a lot will be done, if it triggers again halfway through this, would it not break everything?

Comment: Its hard to tell without knowing the nature of what you are doing. In the best case, you work is idempotent and doesn't matter if its done twice. If you can make it transactional that could work too. In the worst case, you might have to do cleanup. For starters just have a one-bit flag for every job that will indicate if its done or not and make the flag changing the last thing you do.